# Tropical algebra

Tags: tropical-geometry

When we want to study tropical version to any algebraic structure we need to apply tropicalization.
what is the difference between lifting (ring and map such that some properties hold) and tropicalization (which can be viewed as a morphism from the classical Puiseux series system to a tropical system.)?